# Go: "all.bash" compilation testing fails with "permission denied"

Tags: compilation, go, installation

I'm trying to install Golang in a Bluehost shared server.

I've done the following on the server so far:

```
cd ~
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
rm go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
vi .bashrc
```

I set the `.bashrc` file with the local values I want Go to work with.

```
# Configuration for Go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Then I run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
cd ~/go/src
./all.bash
```

And all goes well until the testing:

```
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home1/username/go) has no effect
...
fork/exec /tmp/go-build667300507/cmd/addr2line/_test/addr2line.test: permission denied
FAIL    cmd/addr2line   0.053s
?       cmd/cgo [no test files]
...
```

After that every single test fails, because I don't have access to /tmp. I was thinking maybe there is a variable to set the tests some place I do have access to, but I haven't found it.

About `GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home1/username/go) has no effect`. I've ran:

```
echo $GOROOT
```

And it is not set. So whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `GOROOT` to your `.bashrc`:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go1.3.1.linux-amd64/go
# or, depending how the archive was un-tar'd:
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

`GOPATH` should be set to a **[workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)**, a folder where your projects will reside

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/goprojects
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

You will have `src`, `bin` and `pkg` in `GOPATH`.

---

Remember, the [go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz) archive is for using go directly (it has binaries pre-compiled).

Doing a `all.bash` makes sense only if you build go from sources, but in that case, you would need only the sources ([go1.3.1.src.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.3.1.src.tar.gz)).

Comment: Hey @VonC! Thanks for answering. I added the GOROOT and GOPATH variables to my .bashrc and it got rid of the GOPATH set to GOROOT warning. But the tests are still failing due to a permission denied error.

Comment: @pachanka just to be sure, does a command like `go version` work?

Comment: yup "go version go1.3.1 linux/amd64"

Comment: Then you don't need to do a `./all.bash`: I have edited the answer.

Comment: @panchanka the reason you got permission denied is most likely because in most linux distros /tmp is mounted as tmpfs with the noexec mount option.

Comment: @FUZxxl trying to be extra secure and all that crap, I personally never had noexec set on /tmp since well, everything gets compiled in /tmp.